# How to get Spotify API Auth Code after redirect?

Tags: reactjs, spotify

In my React app, I have a file authorization.js which handles authentication with Spotify API.
There are two functions:

initiateLogin() - redirects user to spotify's authentication page, then calls requestAccessToken(). InitiateLogin() function is called by a button in a component somewhere.

requestAccessToken() - checks the url for 'code', and then uses 'code' to retrieve an access token via API. The token is stored in localstorage.

The problem is that I don't know how to ensure I have redirected to the redirect_uri before calling requestAccessToken(). When initiateLogin() is called, I am redirected to Spotify's login page. Then, by the time I am redirected back to redirect_uri, requestAccessToken has already been attempted and failed because there is no code in the url to retrieve.

The following is what I have: (redirect_uri, client_id, and scopes are defined outside the functions)

requestAccessToken:

```
const requestAccessToken = async () => {
  const location = window.location.href;
  const queries = location.slice(location.indexOf("="));
  const code = queries.substring(1);
  console.log(code);
  const body = new URLSearchParams({
    grant_type: "authorization_code",
    code: code,
    redirect_uri: redirect_uri,
    client_id: client_id,
    client_secret: client_secret,
  });
  const response = await fetch("https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    },
    body,
  });
  if (response.ok) {
    const resp = await response.json();
    // eslint-disable-next-line
    const { access_token, refresh_token, expires_in } = resp;
    localStorage.setItem("token", access_token);
  } else {
    console.error("Access token request failed. Oh no!");
  }
};
```

InitiateLogin:

```
export const initiateLogin = () => {
  const url = `https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=${client_id}&scope=${encodeURIComponent(
    scopes.join(" ")
  )}&redirect_uri=${encodeURIComponent(redirect_uri)}`;

  window.location = url; // Redirects
  requestAccessToken();
};
```

My best guess is to include code inbetween window.location = url; and requestAccessToken();, the last two lines.
However, nothing I've done seems to work.